# How to draw a bipartite with specific node color?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

my code:

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,quotes}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,amat/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
  row sep=1em,draw,dashed,rounded corners,
  nodes={draw,solid,circle,execute at begin node={$v_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}$}}},
  amat2/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
  row sep=1em,draw,dashed,rounded corners,
  nodes={draw,solid,circle,execute at begin node={$u_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}$}}},
  fsnode/.style={fill=myblue},
  ssnode/.style={fill=mygreen}]

 \matrix[amat,nodes=fsnode,label=above:$V^{1}$] (mat1) {\\
 };

 \matrix[amat2,right=2cm of mat1,nodes=ssnode,label=above:$V^{2}$] (mat2) {\\
 \\ 
 \\};

 \draw  (mat1-1-1) edge["$1$"] (mat2-1-1)
  (mat1-1-1) edge["$2$"] (mat2-2-1);

  \draw  (mat1-1-1) edge["$3$"] (mat2-3-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get two sets `V^1` and `V^2`: 
 1. I need the name of the node in `V^2` with the biggest edge value (i.e., the edge with weight 3 in my code) to be with a red color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fill any node `red` by adding `|[fill=red]|`. I hope to interpret your instructions correctly.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,quotes}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,amat/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
  row sep=1em,draw,dashed,rounded corners,
  nodes={draw,solid,circle,execute at begin node={$v_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}$}}},
  amat2/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
  row sep=1em,draw,dashed,rounded corners,
  nodes={draw,solid,circle,execute at begin node={$u_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}$}}},
  fsnode/.style={fill=myblue},
  ssnode/.style={fill=mygreen}]

 \matrix[amat,nodes=fsnode,label=above:$V^{1}$] (mat1) {
 \\
 };

 \matrix[amat2,right=2cm of mat1,nodes=ssnode,label=above:$V^{2}$] (mat2) {\\
 \\ 
 |[fill=red]|\\};

 \draw  (mat1-1-1) edge["$1$"] (mat2-1-1)
  (mat1-1-1) edge["$2$"] (mat2-2-1);

  \draw  (mat1-1-1) edge["$3$"] (mat2-3-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]